# How can I get the different results as I put the number?

Tags: java, arraylist, extends

I wanna get the different results as the inputted number.

For example, when I put 4 I get the results of the rectangle and when I put 3 I get the triangle.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Source9_1 {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int x, y; // 클래스 Parameter(내부 변수)

    Point[] v = new Point[n]

    for(int i=0; i <= v.length; i++) {
        v[i] = new Point();
        v[i].

    }
}

class Point {
    int x, y; // 클래스 Parameter (내부 변수)

    public void setPoint(int x, int y) { // Point 세팅
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void printPoint() { // Point 출력
        System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Point {
    Point[] p = new Point[4];

    Rectangle(Point[] p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class Triangle extends Point {
    Point[] p = new Point[3]; // 3개의 Point인스턴스를 담을 배열 생성

    Triangle(Point[] p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class Shape extends Point { // Point 배열 및 상속을 받아 세팅 후 출력가능한 클래스
    Point coord[10];
    static int s = 0; // 불릴 때마다 값 증가 ???

    public void printShapePoint() { // 배열에 담은 Point 출력

    }

    public void setShapePoint() { // 배열에 담기 위해 Point 증가

    }
}
```

So far, I coded like this but I don't know what to do now.

How can I get the different result as I put the number?

[This is the result what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXcxo.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Take a look on switch-case in Java, probably it will help you

Comment: You have statement codes outside functions. That is not allowed. Shouldn't some of this code be inside a `main` function, maybe?

Comment: @PedroLima oh I missed it, thank you!

Comment: why is rectangle a child class of a point? a rectangle is more like a shape that is defined by points....

Comment: Don't look at the switch statement! It's usually a bad choice, instead try to stick with the object-oriented approach you seem to be taking. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What should the different shape classes do?

Comment: I added some example code here: https://github.com/akoster/x-converter/tree/master/src/main/java/xcon/stackoverflow/shapes See also my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, about your `Rectangle` and `Triangle` classes. I feel like you have missed your point there (pun not intended), because you've put both extending the `Point` class. That doesn't make much sense, since you have the `Shape` class, which would do a much better job as the superclass for them.

So:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    ...
}

class Triangle extends Shape {
    ...
}
```

With that out of the way, what you have so far:

1. You are capturing the number of points from the input;
2. You are creating an array of that size;
3. You are instantiating and setting an `Point` object for each of the array positions.

What you need to do next:

1. Capture the points coordinates from the input
2. Set said coordinates to the `Point` objects
3. Instantiate an `Triangle` or `Rectangle` object, depending on how many points you have.

So, inside your `for` statement you will want to do:

```
for (int i=0; i <= v.length; i++) {
    v[i] = new Point();
    x = sc.nextInt(); // Save 'x' value into the variable
    y = sc.nextInt(); // Save 'y' value into the variable
    v[i].setPoint(x, y); // Set both values using the method from Point
}
```

Then, since both `Rectangle` and `Triangle` have `Shape` as a common superclass, you are allowed to put objects of either one of these class in a `Shape` variable. So right after the `for` statement you will want to do:

```
Shape s; // Create the empty variable here, so it will exist outside the if-else scope
if (n == 3)
    s = new Triangle(v);
else
    s = new Rectangle(v);
```

Finally, just print your points:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
    v[i].printPoint();
```

And that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations! Though I didn't get everything you told yet but it was really helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Pedro is great. I have an additional suggestion to make. Using a switch or conditional to create the different types of shapes is a bit of a code smell. I suggest using an abstract factory for this. I put up a little example of how you could do this [here](https://github.com/akoster/x-converter/tree/master/src/main/java/xcon/stackoverflow/shapes).

Deducing the shape from the number of points might be insufficient. For instance, a rectangle is defined by two points (not four) and so would a line, even though you are not currently modeling lines.

I think it would be more clear to select the shape by name and use a factory to instantiate it from the entered points.

Note that he shapes object hierarchy is used a lot to explain object orientation. There are several pitfalls with designing class structures like this. See for example [this article](https://medium.com/@cscalfani/goodbye-object-oriented-programming-a59cda4c0e53). Keep in mind also the Liskov Substitution principle which is easily violated, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).